State and Timers are not working as expected in Apache Beam
I have this code snippet.
class UserAccessInfo(beam.DoFn):
    # State to store the access data for a user during the day
    ACCESS_STATE = BagStateSpec('access_state', StrUtf8Coder())
    CLEAR_TIMER = TimerSpec('clear', TimeDomain.REAL_TIME)

    def process(self, element, timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam, access_state=beam.DoFn.StateParam(ACCESS_STATE), clear_timer=beam.DoFn.TimerParam(CLEAR_TIMER)):
        user_key, log = element
        print('Current log: ', log)
        user_id = log['actor']['user']['uuid']
        location_id = log['location']['uuid']
        access_date = log['date']
        event_time = datetime.fromisoformat(log['time'][:-1])  # Parsing time
        
        # Retrieve the current access state
        current_state = list(access_state.read())
        if current_state:
            # We have existing state, load entry and exit info
            entry_info = json.loads(current_state[0])
            exit_info = json.loads(current_state[-1])
        else:
            # No previous data, initialize state
            entry_info = None
            exit_info = None

        # Update entry and exit based on the event time
        if entry_info is None or event_time < entry_info['event_time']:
            # Update entry time and door if it's earlier
            entry_info = {
                'user_uuid': user_id,
                'location_uuid': location_id,
                'access_date': access_date,
                'event_time': log['time'],
                'door': log['door']['name'],
                'type': 'entry'
            }

        if exit_info is None or event_time > exit_info['event_time']:
            # Update exit time and door if it's later
            exit_info = {
                'user_uuid': user_id,
                'location_uuid': location_id,
                'access_date': access_date,
                'event_time': log['time'],
                'door': log['door']['name'],
                'type': 'exit'
            }

        print('\nEntry info: ', entry_info)
        print('\nExit info: ', exit_info)
        # Store the updated state (entry first, exit last)
        access_state.clear()
        access_state.add(json.dumps(entry_info))
        access_state.add(json.dumps(exit_info))

        print('Current state: ', list(access_state.read()))
        
        # Set the timer to fire at the end of the day (e.g., midnight)
        try:
            current_time = timestamp.to_utc_datetime()
        except OverflowError:
            current_time = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)  # Ensure it's timezone-aware

        clear_time = current_time + timedelta(seconds=60)
        
        print('\nClear time: ', clear_time)
        # Set the timer for 60 seconds from the current processing time
        clear_timer.set(clear_time)

        # Yield current access info to give real-time results
        yield {
            'user_uuid': entry_info['user_uuid'],
            'location_uuid': entry_info['location_uuid'],
            'access_date': entry_info['access_date'],
            'entry_time': entry_info['event_time'],
            'entry_door': entry_info['door'],
            'exit_time': exit_info['event_time'],
            'exit_door': exit_info['door']
        }
        
    @on_timer(CLEAR_TIMER)
    def clear_state(self, access_state=beam.DoFn.StateParam(ACCESS_STATE)):
        # Clear the state at the end of the day
        
        print('Clearing state...')
        access_state.clear()
        print('\nState cleared!\n')


As you can see I have set the timer to clear the state after 60 seconds, and the code is not throwing any error, but after 60 seconds it should run the clear_state function, but it is not doing so because of which my state is not getting cleared.
Can you please help me here how to clear the state?

How often do you get incoming data per user_key? Each time a new element is ingested, you are resetting your timer by 60s. If you ingest more than one element per minute, the timer never expires.

I am sending the new one after 60 seconds, still it is not calling the clear state function

You can try the windowing in Beam. This will allow you to group elements based on time or other criteria. You can define a window that aligns with your desired clearing interval. When the window closes, the timer will fire, and the clear_state callback will be executed. This is a more robust and efficient way to handle periodic state clearing.
